# Можно ли определить, в каком отрезке мы находимся за О(1)?

Tags: алгоритм, любой-язык

Приветствую. Пишу рандом с весами и нужно решить следующую задачу.
На входе у меня есть, например, такой массив `A = [1,3,7,10]` и число `n ∈ [min(A); max(A))`. Будем считать, что [1;3) - первый полуинтервал, [3;7) - второй, и так далее. Можно ли определять в каком интервале (первом, втором, ...) находится данное число n за константное время? Понятно, что это легко реализуется циклом.

Comment: Двоичный поиск за O(log k) (k — длина массива). Быстрее, думаю, нельзя. ЗЫ: а что такое «рандом с весами»?

Comment: Если использовать только ваш массив A, то никак. Какие ограничения на числа? Можно ли создать заранее дополнительную структуру данных?

Comment: @VladD его еще отсортировать нужно будет тогда... Хотя я тоже думал про двоичный поиск. Рандом с весами - чтобы можно было задавать вероятность выпадения определенных элементов. Я строю массив отрезков по вероятностям(бОльшей вероятности соответствует бОльший отрезок), а потом определяю в какой отрезок попало число. Это вообще как, нормальная схема?

Comment: @Zergatul в этой абстрактной задаче ограничений никаких. В моем применении сумма элементов массива = 1; каждый элемент > 0.

Comment: Если точность элементов ограничена (например 6 знаков после запятой), можно создать массив длиной 1 миллион (`B`), и заполнить его номерами отрезков. Теперь для выполнения поиска вы будете писать: `int x = B[n * 1000000]`. Это и будет `O(1)`.

Comment: @Zergatul это очевидное решение, но лучше уж даже циклом пройтись, чем такие затраты памяти.

Comment: "ограничений никаких", "4мб - большие затраты памяти", я вас понял.

Comment: @Zergatul вы спрашивали об ограничениях на числа, я ответил на этот вопрос. Из текста задачи понятно, что речь идет об оптимизации решения задачи.

Comment: так входной массив изначально отсортирован или нет ?

Comment: не помещайте информацию необходимую для ответа в комментарии к своему ответу. Отредактируйте ваш вопрос вместо этого. Можно [edit] кнопку нажать.¶ Поместите более характерный пример в вопрос (неотсортированный массив, числа с плавающей точкой), какие порядки величин в задаче (миллиард интервалов или нет), точность с которой ответ нужен (к примеру, 3 знака после запятой, все числа от 0 до 1 не включая), ограничения на память (O(1) в памяти).

Comment: @Nik Можно сделать предвычисленную таблицу произвольного допустимого размера любого. В этой таблице хранить отображение из некоторого количества старших самых значимых разрядов числа в список отрезков в которые это число отображается. Потом делаем переход в один из списков в таблице и просто линейно проверяем все отрезки, если числа отсортированы (что логично для таблицы распределения вероятностей) тогда можно делать внутри списка бинарный поиск. В итоге если даже небольшая таблица будет на 1000 индексов то мы сократим сложность поиска в 1000 раз одним скачком в нужный индекс таблицы.

Comment: @Nik Реализовал предложенное мной решение на основе предвычисленной таблицы заданного любого желаемого размера, запостил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. точной информации от автора не получили по поводу ограничений в задаче, в итоге решил я задачу со своими ограничениями. Я решил для отсортированной последовательности чисел (т.к. я предположил что автор строит нечто типа таблицы распределения вероятности, кумулятивная вероятность и в ней хочет быстро искать), также для целых чисел (для вещественных легко обобщить), также моё решение будет наилучшим образом работать для более менее равномерно распределённых чисел (иначе будет медленней работать). Суть моего решения заключается в том, что я использовал предвычисленную таблицу для ускорения нахождения нужного интервала, для этого я разбил весь интервал [min, max] на c_table_size вёдер ("bucket", или интервалов) равного размера (округлил в большую сторону), таблица индексируется по номеру ведра а значения таблицы это индексы первых номеров чисел которые попали в данное ведро, получается что для заданного ведра интервал индексов в исходной последовательности это `[table[bucket], table[bucket + 1])`, т.е. благодаря таблице при равномерном распределении чисел мы уменьшаем интервал поиска в c_table_size (размер таблицы) раз, а таблица очень компактная - c_table_size 32-битных чисел, её можно на любой подходящий размер сделать, сколько не жалко. Поиск по интервалу предсказанному таблицей я делаю через линейный цикл, конечно можно и нужно сделать бинарный поиск но это уже я оставляю на доработку автором. Замеры времени показали, что таблица например размером в 1024 элемента ускоряет где-то в 1000 раз поиск.

Вот полный исходный код на C++, [можно запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NM2D/0):

```
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

typedef uint32_t u32;
typedef uint32_t s32;
typedef uint64_t u64;

enum {
    c_nums_min = 1 << 10,
    c_nums_max = 1 << 20,
    c_nums_cnt = 1 << 16,
    c_table_size = 1 << 10,
    c_num_tests = 1 << 16,
};

class TimeMeasure {
public:
    TimeMeasure(string const & name) {
        name_ = name;
        start_time_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        end_time_ = start_time_;
    }

    u64 TimeElapsedNS() {
        end_time_ = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        u64 diff = chrono::duration_cast<chrono::nanoseconds>(end_time_ - start_time_).count();
        return diff;
    }

    ~TimeMeasure() {
        cout << "Time elapsed for [" << name_ << "] = " << dec << TimeElapsedNS() / 1000000 << " ms." << endl;
    }
private:
    string name_;
    chrono::time_point<chrono::high_resolution_clock> start_time_, end_time_;
};

int main() {
    // Initialize random number generator.
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<u32> distribution(c_nums_min, c_nums_max);
    auto rng = std::bind(distribution, generator);

    // Generate random numbers.
    vector<u32> nums(c_nums_cnt);
    for (u32 i = 0; i < nums.size(); ++i) {
        nums[i] = rng();
    }
    nums.push_back(c_nums_min);
    nums.push_back(c_nums_max + 1);

    // Sort numbers.
    sort(nums.begin(), nums.end());

    // Create lookup table.
    vector<u32> table(c_table_size + 1);
    u32 const c_bucket_size = (c_nums_max - c_nums_min + c_table_size) / c_table_size;
    for (u32 i = 0, i_nums = 0; i < table.size() - 1; ++i) {
        u32 const bucket_end = c_nums_min + (i + 1) * c_bucket_size;
        table[i] = i_nums;
        while (i_nums < nums.size() - 1 && nums[i_nums] < bucket_end) ++i_nums;
    }
    table.back() = nums.size() - 1;

    // Generate random nums for queries.
    vector<u32> query_nums(c_num_tests);
    for (u32 i = 0; i < query_nums.size(); ++i) {
        query_nums[i] = rng();
    }

    // Do lookups.
    {
        TimeMeasure time_measure("AllTests");

        for (u32 i = 0; i < query_nums.size(); ++i) {
            u32 n = query_nums[i];
            if (n < c_nums_min || n > c_nums_max) {
                cout << "Wrong n: " << n << endl;
                return -1;
            }
            u32 table_index = (n - c_nums_min) / c_bucket_size;
            u32 found_index = max(u32(1), table[table_index]) - 1;
            for (u32 j = table[table_index]; j < table[table_index + 1]; ++j) {
                if (n < nums[j + 1]) {
                    if (nums[j] <= n) {
                        found_index = j;
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!(nums[found_index] <= n && n < nums[found_index + 1])) {
                cout << "Incorrect algorithm!" << endl
                     << n << " [" << nums[found_index] << ", " << nums[found_index + 1] << ")" << endl;
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```